# Which policy to grant to IAM user to create lambda deployment package in Python?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

I want to create a lamba deployment package in python (with dependencies) using the Amazon tutorial.

When I push the .zip package with

```
aws lambda update-function-code --function-name my-function --zip-file fileb://function.zip
```

I get the following error

```
An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the UpdateFunctionCode operation: 
User: arn:aws:iam::<ACCOUNT-ID>:user/jeanclaude is not authorized to perform: lambda:UpdateFunctionCode 
on resource: arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-3:<ACCOUNT-ID>:function:my-function
```

Which policy should I grant to jeanclaude to give him the correct access?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The **User** created in **AWS IAM** which is configured with your **AWS CLI** using access_key and secret_key should have enough privileges to interact with AWS Lambda.
- I would prefer `AWSLambdaFullAccess` policy attached to your User/Role. This is just for testing purpose and later you can reduce the privileges if you want.
- Once you have done the above then if you run the command

```
aws lambda update-function-code --function-name "helloworld" --zip-file "fileb://./helloworld.zip" --region "eu-west-2"
```

it should work, note that for `update-function-code` mandatory field is just the `--function-name` other fields are optional.[aws cli update-fuction-code](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/update-function-code.html)

- Also please take a note of the `create-function` command it has just the following fields as mandatory and all other are optional [aws cli docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/create-function.html)

```
 create-function
--function-name <value>
--runtime <value>
--role <value>
--handler <value>
```

and the `--role` here is the role required by the lambda while executing to interact with other services (not to be confused by the user above)

Comment: `AWSLambdaFullAccess` was the missing part

Answer (score 1):

The user needs permission to `UpdateFunctionCode` for that ARN. More specific information is [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_UpdateFunctionCode.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can create a policy granting `UpdateFunctionCode`, assign the policy to a group, and then assign the group to the user.

Your policy should look like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Allow UpdateFunctionCode",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "lambda:UpdateFunctionCode",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:<account_id>:function:your_function"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```